# Android Mixing OpenGLES 1.0 and OpenGLES 2.0

Tags: android, opengl-es, opengl-es-2.0

I've been asked to create shaders for our Android engine and I'm a little confused. So far the engine has been built on the premise that we use GL10 instances to be responsbile for the drawing of everything. But because shaders are OpenGL 2.0 if I were to set the context client version to 2.0 and draw a simple scene (say a cube) nothing appears whereas it does if I use the default 1.0.

I'm not entirely sure how I should proceed - do I need to create different engines based on the highest level version of OpenGLES supported by the device? Use the higest possible regardless of what it can support (assuming backward compatibility)?

Any help/suggestions appreciated...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

OpenGL ES 2.x is not backward compatible with OpenGL ES 1.x. You have to write different code to support both of them.

Comment: Ok in case anybody else is curious.

I wrote a static class to determine what were the capabilities of the phone on startup, taking consideration of false positives by catching NoSuchMethodErrors. Based on the results I use a single renderer and version of the engine and apply specific instructions i.e. if it can have a programmable pipeline then use it, otherwise used the fixed pipeline.